# Ontologies only built with classes and not class instances

Tags: owl, ontology, semantic-web, knowledge-graph

I am wondering why public biomedical ontologies are often organized in such a way that there are no class instances and only classes? I understand it in a way that all instances are classes, but I do not understand what is the advantage or purpose of such modelling? Those classes have also only annotation properties. For example NCIT ontology: https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NCIT/?p=summary.
I would appreciate if someone could provide me with an explanation what is the purpose of such model and if there is an advantage to a model where classes have class instances. I am definitively not an expert in the field and I only was working on modelling 'standard' ontologies with classes and their instances.

Comment: szuszfol, can you include in your question an example how you would model it using instances?

Comment: @horcrux In RDF I can say `<my_chocolate_bar> skos:broader <chocolate>` and `<chocolate> skos:broader <food>`. You can use both classes and "prototypes" to describe a taxonomy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**

The reason for preferring classes over individuals (or instances) is that classes allow for sophisticated reasoning which is used to infer classification hierarchies.

**The longer answer**

The semantics of OWL allows you to make the following type of statements:

1. `ClassExpression1` is a `subclass` of `ClassExpression2`
2. `PropertyExpression1` is a `subproperty` of `PropertyExpression2`
3. Individual `c1` is an instance of `Class1`
4. Individual `x` is related to individual `y` via `property1`

Of these 4 options, (1) by far allows for the most sophistication. Intuitively it comes down to how much each of these allow you to express and the  reasoning capability to derive inferences from those statements. To get an intuitive feel of this, using the [OWL Direct Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/), we can see what
`ClassExpression1` and `ClassExpression2` can be substituted with:
[image]

There no way that this expressivity can be achieved using individuals.

**Individuals vs Classes**

In your question you say that all instances (individuals) are classes. This is not exactly true. Rather, classes consists of instances or instances belong to classes. From a mathematical perspective classes are sets and individuals are members of a set.

**Annotations in biomedical ontologies**

These ontologies have a substantial (80%-90%)  amount of annotations. However, they do have lots of logical axioms. You can see it for example when you look at [http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/NCIT_C12392](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies/ncit/terms?iri=http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FNCIT_C12392) on the righthandside, if you scroll down to the bottom, you will see the axioms listed:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Henriette for great explanation!