# ALC: define an ALC Knowledge Base

Tags: description-logic

Hello I am new to description logics and ALC and I find it confusing defining a KB.
More specifically I am trying to create an ALC KB for the first 3 sentences below and
an ALC formula φ that formalizes the last one.

**Sentences:**

• Anna is a person.

• The only kind of coffee that Anna drinks is latte.

• A French is a person who drinks only latte coffee.

• Anna is French.

**My KB so far**:

**TBox T:**

French ≡ Person ⊓ ∀drinks.Latte

**Abox A:**

Person(ANNA), drinks(ANNA, LATTE)

**φ:** French(ANNA)

My questions are:

1. Is it wrong that I considered **latte** as **concept** or I should have written **∀drinks.Coffee** instead, because coffee could be considered also a concept?
2. Is the assertion **drinks(ANNA, LATTE)** redundant because in the Tbox  **∀drinks.Latte** exists?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can model `Person`, `French`, `Coffee` and `Latte` as concepts with the following axioms:

```
French ⊑ Person
Latte ⊑ Coffee
```

The axiom `French ≡ Person ⊓ ∀drinks.Latte` may be problematic. The reason being that the reasoner will infer whenever an individual `x` is a `Person` and `x` only drinks coffee, that `x` is `French`. But it is completely possible that there are people who only drink only lattes but they are not necessarily French. For that reason it is better to express it as follows:

```
French ⊑ Person ⊓ ∀drinks.Latte
```

If you now have `ANNA` as an individual and you assert `French(ANNA)`, this is sufficient. I.e., the reasoner will "know" that `ANNA` drinks only lattes. However, if you do this in Protege (for example), the reasoner will not infer that `ANNA` only drinks lattes. The reason for this is that `ANNA` is in essence an instance of the complex concept expression `Person ⊓ ∀drinks.Latte`, because we said she is French. Reasoners give inferences in terms of named concepts only because in general there can be an infinite number of inferences in terms of complex concept expressions.

To see that the reasoner "knows" this. Create another sublass of `Coffee` class, say `Expresso` that is disjoint with `Latte`. Create an instance of `Expresso`, say `EXPRESSO` and assert `drinks(ANNA, EXPRESSO)`. Running the reasoner now will cause an inconsistency.

As for your question regarding modeling `Latte` as concept or an individual: usually it is better to model as a class. I explain this for OWL in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74574370/ontologies-only-built-with-classes-and-not-class-instances/74575916#74575916). This holds to true for ALC as well.

If you want understand more about when to use equivalence versus subsumption, I have written about this on my blog [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2021/12/23/equivalentto-versus-subclassof/).